# using websocket .net client to access NEST endpoint

Tags: nest-api

I am trying to use a .net websocket client to integrate with the NEST API.
After looking at the firebase client message exchange I am doing something like this:

HTTP Get :
**wss://developer-api.nest.com/.ws?v=5&auth=c.5eJRrs...**

I get back the wss handshake response:

Handshake header: HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Handshake header: Upgrade: websocket
Handshake header: Connection: Upgrade
Handshake header: Sec-WebSocket-Accept: xJqf+mW/6pyGy8/jAXF2yXsCg4w=
Handshake header:
Expected sec key: xJqf+mW/6pyGy8/jAXF2yXsCg4w=
Response sec key: xJqf+mW/6pyGy8/jAXF2yXsCg4w=
Connected
Text frame received: **{"t":"c","d":{"t":"h","d":{"ts":1418645751807,"v":"5","h":"firebase-apiserver02-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553","s":"session366481450"}}}**

And from here on .. I don't know exactly what to do...
It would seem that the received frame is a redirect.
But I have no ideea what is the NEST api expressed in websocket messages.

Can something like this be found somewhere ?
Is NEST prepared to support other websocket clients than those provided by firebase ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with .net

It just acts like a websocket, so you must be able to do something like this.

```
HTTP Get : wss://firebase-apiserver02-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553/.ws?v=5&auth=c.5eJRrs....
```

Sometimes Nest changes the server where your nest data will be saved. so you might need to automaticaly get the redirect from the response you got.

hope this helps